# Python translated to Java conversion does not return correctly

Tags: java, python, translate

I'm trying to convert this python code, that when given a number well return a string based on the number given to correctly weight out the two numbers:

```
def answer(weight):
    instructions = []
    steps = number_of_steps(weight)

    for n in xrange(steps):
        i = instruction_index(n, weight)
        instructions.append(['-', 'R', 'L'][i])

    return instructions


def number_of_steps(weight):
    return int(log(weight * 2, 3)) + 1


def instruction_index(n, weight):
    offset = (3 ** n - 1) / 2

    corrected = int((weight + offset) / 3 ** n)

    return corrected % 3
```

I tried converting it to java in this code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.Math.*;

public class Answer {   

    public static String[] answer(int weight) { 

        ArrayList<String> listOfWeightLocations = new ArrayList<String>();
        int numberOfSteps = numberOfSteps(weight);
        String[] pattern = {"-", "R", "L"};

        for (int index = 0; index <= numberOfSteps; index++) {
            int solution = instructions(index, weight);
            listOfWeightLocations.add(pattern[solution] + 1); //Add one
        }

        String[] listAnswer = listOfWeightLocations.toArray(new String[listOfWeightLocations.size()]);
        return listAnswer;
    }

    public static int numberOfSteps(int weight) {
        int numOfSteps = (int) Math.floor(logOfBase(weight * 2, 3)) + 1;
        return numOfSteps;
    }

    public static double logOfBase(int base, int num) {
        return Math.log(num) / Math.log(base);
    }

    public static int instructions(int index, int weight) {
        double offset = (Math.pow(3, index) - 1)  / 2;
        int corrected = (int) Math.floor((weight + offset) / Math.pow(3, index));

        return (corrected % 3);
    }
}
```

But it returns the wrong value every time. Is there any fault in the conversion and can it be fixed? Sorry for a lot of code, and a UN-sytaxed question, but I really need help with this. Thank You!!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We could use error reporting better than "the wrong value".  Please put in the customary print statements to track input and output values of your methods; this may well show you the error without any further input from us.  If not, it will help us track the problem.